The Odd Message
The Message
My friend sent me a quite odd text message. I asked him in person after he sent it but he said he did not remember texting it. I am very suspicious.

Hello user5127! I have something to show you:
happiness = YXRvYg==
question = 64
nine = WW91I
hungry = corn
acorn = fifty
hang = bang
ten = HRocm93IGF3YXkgbXkg
party = ZWFzdGVyIGVnZw==
one = less
angry = hungry
million = big
seventy = b3V0c2lkZSwgeW91
five = IGNvb2sgbXkgaW5zaWRlLiBU
usermod = aG
full = VuI
finite = Hlvd
text = SBlYXQ
gigabytes = gb
twitter = X
twenty = five
two = one
moan = k
word = gb
ahem = 3V0c2lkZ
sed = SB
two = twine
html = hbmQ
what = geW91IHRocm93

In the next text message (five days later), he sent me:

Oops! I forgot something!
bag = IGF3YXkgbXkgaW5zaWRlLi
fish = ten
fun = zero
not = BXaGF0IGFtIEk/

I texted back "angry". He came to my house that day and said, "I actually did send that message. You got it correct!"
What did I get correct? Why did I send "angry" back? Show work with complete steps.
Hints
Hint 1:

 The riddle tag means something.

Hint 2:

 happiness

Hint 3:

 base 64

Hint 4 (might give something away):

 There is a concealed riddle.

--user5127
P.S. - I am not very good at setting tags so if it is wrong, please fix it.

The first message, YXRvYg==,

 is base64 encoding of atob, a function that can decode base64.

 Several of the other chunks also seem base64-like:


 The right-hand sides of each of the yellow-highlighted ones: nine, ten, seventy, five, usermod, etc... can be concatenated together to form a very long base64 string.

 This string decodes to: You throw away my outside, you cook my inside. Then you eat my outside and you throw away my inside. What am I?

 This is a classic riddle, the answer to which is corn (you throw away the husk, then cook the remainder; then you eat the kernels and throw away the cob).

 Two other given equivalences are hungry = corn and angry = hungry. So the response was angry.

It's not clear to me what the purpose of the remaining parts is: the left-hand sides of the base64 string, the other unused equivalences, the party string decoding to "easter egg"... but this does appear to get the correct answer.

The left hand sides and the unused equivalences are used to make it complicated. The party string decodes to easter egg as a joke.

Was it too easy?

@user5127 I wouldn't say "too easy", more "too insubstantial". [1] Red herrings are almost always a very bad idea for puzzles: you want your puzzle to give an "aha!" moment, not "I guess it's this?"; the more unused information there is, the less satisfying. Everything should fit together. [2] A puzzle being easy isn't inherently bad. There are easy puzzles that are very good!

[3] This puzzle didn't really have anything to it other than "base64" - which most puzzlers will recognize immediately - and a riddle which is already on this site. All of the rest was useless. That's why I felt there was really not any 'substance' to it.
